# SQL Query selecting 2 tables and displaying spesific data

Tags: mysql

I have tried to select data from 2 tables. Where kills from name should be visible. But I can't seem to get the SQL query to be correct. I would also add a spesific type as "Player". So that it wouldn't list other mobs.

```
SELECT * FROM `Stats_kill`.`Stats_players` ORDER BY `amount`.`name` ASC
```

Here's the tables:
Stats_kill: https://i.gyazo.com/0eba32be143afcf68db24c8437614374.png
Stats_players: https://i.gyazo.com/16d4bec7a83fae98f4ac2c2096fba515.png

Basically it'll be a leaderboard displaying 1-X in the position of most kills.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `Stats_kill`.`Stats_players` 
WHERE Stats_kill.player_id = Status_players.player_id
ORDER BY `amount`.`name` ASC
```